# MapBox Compose Extension: Mutating MapInitOptions during composition is not allowed exception

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to use `MapBox` in Compose and set the needed location on the map using `mapViewportState.flyTo()` function but it fails with the mentioned exception for some reason, and it's related to using `mapInitOptionsFactory = { MapInitOptions(...) }`, if I remove `mapInitOptionsFactory` line code then it works, but it means of course I get default map style

```
val mapViewportState = rememberMapViewportState
LaunchedEffect(key1 = userInitialLocation) {
    userInitialLocation?.let { userLocation ->
        mapViewportState.flyTo(
            cameraOptions = mapViewportState.cameraState.toCamera
                .center(
                    Point.fromLngLat(
                        userLocation.longitude,
                       userLocation.latitude
                    )
                )
                .zoom(16.0)
                .build()
        )
    }
}
val context = LocalContext.current
if (isLocationPermissionGranted) {
    MapboxMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        mapViewportState = mapViewportState,
         mapInitOptionsFactory = { // if I comment out this part then it works fine
             MapInitOptions(
                 context = context,
                 styleUri = Style.DARK,
             )
         }
    )
```

Logcat:

```
Error was captured in composition while live edit was enabled.
                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mutating MapInitOptions during composition is not allowed.
                    at com.mapbox.maps.extension.compose.internal.MapboxMapNodeKt$MapboxMapComposeNode$2$1.invoke(MapboxMapNode.kt:136)
                    at com.mapbox.maps.extension.compose.internal.MapboxMapNodeKt$MapboxMapComposeNode$2$1.invoke(MapboxMapNode.kt:135)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$apply$operation$1.invoke(Composer.kt:1712)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$apply$operation$1.invoke(Composer.kt:1710)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(Composition.kt:818)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges(Composition.kt:849)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:625)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:537)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:41)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1229)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:827)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapInitOptionsFactory` has it own context

`mapInitOptionsFactory = { context -> // use this context }`

In your example:

```
// val context = LocalContext.current // Remove this
    MapboxMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            mapViewportState = mapViewportState,
            mapInitOptionsFactory = {context->
                MapInitOptions(
                    context = context,
                    styleUri = Style.DARK,
            )
        }
    )
```

[Source: Mapbox github - Setup the Map Style and set the initial camera position](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/blob/v11.0.0-rc.1/extension-compose/README.md#setup-the-map-style-and-set-the-initial-camera-position)